# How to in Jmeter parse JSON over values that do not match Regex expression?

Tags: regex, json, jmeter

I am having problems parsing through a JSON response. It basically returns a JSON array of objects such as

```
[
  {"id":"123","value":"abc","description":"something"},
  {"id":"456","value":null,"description":"something else"},
  {"id":"789","value":"def","description":"something more"}
]
```

When I use the following regex expression

```
"id":"(.+?)","value":(?!null),"description":"(.+?)"
```

in the Regular Expression Extractor I get the following result:

```
variable[0][1]:123, variable[0][2]:something
variable[1][1]:456, variable[1][2]:something more
```

which is wrong since the match must have be broken in the second object and not picked up the second id and use the third object's description. I am expecting the id to be 789 not 456.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer. I needed to break the match if there was a } bracket in between the words such as

```
"id":"(.+?)"[^\}]*"value":(?!null)[^\}]*"description":"(.+?)"
```

easy fix :)